# Can't create OverbyteICS simple TCP server, without echo and without line mode

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-xe2

** EDIT **
OK : bad question : my pb was not in my code but in the PuTTY configuration !!
As I have some informations to add, I don't close the question. I will do it and put an answer.

---

I use the OverbyteICS (very good) library (V8) in Delphi XE2. I just have a problem trying to create a very basic TCP server which display a Telnet client (like PuTTY) chars (in real time) without resend them to the client (no echo). 
I used some examples from ICS mainly OverbyteIcsSrvDemo or OverbyteIcsTcpSrv but I have alaways the same problem : if I ECHO all is OK, but if I don't ECHO the Telnet client have to send CR + LF  to display the chars.

My test code is here : http://collabedit.com/9f9h4

I tried to play with some properties like LineMode without success.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Is your client sending every character as it is typed by a human user? You have not shown the client code. You don't show the code of your server either, and you expect someone to debug your client and your server which we can't see? Don't bother posting a wall of code. Debug your own code. I don't know what your Client object is or why you're trying to read one byte at a time via RcvdLine. You seem confused.

Comment: Sure my question is not clear ! Some informations : the client is just a classic one like Putty or Hyperterminal, and the servet is the classical examples from OverbyteICS with 2 the lines modified. But you are right I will edit my question, surely with an link to my example. !

Comment: So you want to write a chat-like application with putty as a client. You should learn what a VT102 TTY is, and how for example, Putty and how TELNET-like sessions are done. You also should not try to learn how to do this like you have done, you started out with a flawed assumption; Using putty is not a good idea. You should WRITE your own client and then write your own server. Then you can add logging and know what is going on.  Ignorance of TCP/IP and the socket api concepts is your problem. Start with an ICS Chat client and ICS Chat server demo.  Observe working code. Read docs.

Comment: Hi Warren, thx for your answer. As you may be seen, my pb was in my wrong configuration of PuTTY. Using PuTTY is, for me, a good idea if you use raw mode and delete all the 'configuration' options.

Comment: If your goal is to learn how things work, writing the client and server yourself is better. If your goal is to avoid knowing how things work, then you're doing it right.

Comment: Strange vision of technical things. When I use PuTTY it is not to "avoid knowing how things work" it is to have a robust and well done TCP client for testing my server.

Answer (score 0):

As yet explained in my question, my piece of code was OK but my PuTTY was not well configured.
The main problem was that the option "Terminal/Local Line editing" was on 'Auto' so PuTTY was waiting the 'return' key to send the string.
I also was disturbed because when I send put the echo on (on my code) for some reasons PuTTY was sending chars without waiting for 'return'.